# Javascript Test unit with Jest an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs, testunit

too many divergent posts upon googling to choose a clear and up-to-date solution...

I wrote 3 tests to check different possibilities

**===========. TEST 1 OK ================**

**// helloJest.js**

```
function sayHello() {
  return "hello there jest"
}
module.exports = sayHello;
```

**// helloJestTest**

```
const sayHello = require('../../src/client/js/helloJest');
test('string returning hello there jest', () => {// 
  expect(sayHello()).toEqual('hello there jest');
});
```

**===========. TEST 2 FAILING ================**

**// helloJest.js**

```
function sayHello() {
  return "hello there jest"
}
export default { sayHello }; // <= changed
```

**// helloJestTest**

```
const sayHello = require('../../src/client/js/helloJest');
test('string returning hello there jest', () => {// 
  expect(sayHello()).toEqual('hello there jest');
});

TypeError: sayHello is not a function

      3 |
      4 | test('string returning hello there jest', () => {//
    > 5 |   expect(sayHello()).toEqual('hello there jest');
        |          ^
      6 | });
      7 |
```

**===========. TEST 3 FAILING ================**

**// helloJest.js**

```
function sayHello() {
  return "hello there jest"
}
export default { sayHello }; //  <= changed
```

**// helloJestTest**

```
import { sayHello } from '../../src/client/js/helloJest'; // <= changed
test('string returning hello there jest', () => {// 
  expect(sayHello()).toEqual('hello there jest');
});

    TypeError: (0 , _helloJest.sayHello) is not a function

      3 |
      4 | test('string returning hello there jest', () => {//
    > 5 |   expect(sayHello()).toEqual('hello there jest');
        |          ^
      6 | });
```

How to pass the TEST 3 correctly ???

I am using the following packages

**package.json**

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
...
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js"],
    "transform": { "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest" },
    "testRegex": "/tests/.*\\.(js)$"
  }
```

and I have in

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between 2 and 3? You only seem to have made half the change; in both cases the default export is an *object*, not just the function.

Comment: did you try in your test2 to do `const { sayHello } = 
 require('../../src/client/js/helloJest');`

Comment: In 2. ( export default ES6 , require() ) 
In 3. ( export default ES6, import ES6 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're tripping up in a couple of places there. Primarily: You don't use `{}` with the default import/export.

This:

```
export default { sayHello };
```

exports an **object** as the default export of the module. The object has a single property, `sayHello`, referring to the function. To make the *function* the default export, don't use the `{}`:

```
export default sayHello;
```

Then, when *importing*, if you want the default import, don't use `{}`:

```
import sayHello from '../../src/client/js/helloJest';
```

---

If you want to export a *named* export, you do use `{}`:

```
export { sayHello };
```

and

```
import { sayHello } from '../../src/client/js/helloJest';
```

---

Examples of both on plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/f8PhOhULphQUrVXwdXF3/

Comment: it's ok with default...  however it seems that  Jest does not like import a named export ....

Comment: @erwin - You're sure you're exporting it correctly? It would be odd if Jest had a problem with named exports.

Comment: @erwin one thing that tripped me up for a while. `{}` is not destructuring. It is just importing _named exports_ from the module.

Answer (score 1):

**TEST 2**

You do export as default an object with a single property which is the `sayHello` function, so you should import it in jest through the following:

`const { sayHello } = require('../../src/client/js/helloJest');`

**TEST 3**

Again you do export as above. 
In this case you can import it as the following:

`import Hello from '../../src/client/js/helloJest';`

And then you should be able to use your func as:

`Hello.sayHello`

Comment: That's it !!! I got it right now in Test 3 ... and understood all 3 tests ... thanks a lot !!!